# How would I add array index's together?

Tags: java, arrays, addition

I've read data from a text file and stored them in an array called 'boat1'.
There are nine values and I am trying to add together index's [4] to [9] to get a total value.

How would I go about doing this?

Here is my code:

```
    String[] boat1 = new String[9];
    int i = 0;
    while(reader.hasNextLine() && i < boat1.length) {
        boat1[i] = reader.nextLine();
        i++;
    }
```

I've tried to change the values to an integer but it doesn't seem to be working..?

Thank you.

Comment: what exactly do you want?

Comment: There is no element with index 9 in String[9], the indices would go from 0 to 8.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean you read numbers and you want to sum them. Either you read them as int or other numerical type  reader.nextInt(), or you parse them to ints, Integer.parseInt(boat1[i]);

Answer (score 1):

You got to parse before adding:

```
int a = Integer.parseInt(boat1[3]);
int b = Integer.parseInt(boat1[8]);
int c = a + b;
```

Your array `boat1` is a `String` array and not an `int` array.  You need to convert it. Note that `boat1` is size of `9` meaning that it has indexes from `0` to `8`. Java is 0 based.

If you want to add up a sequence of numbers (ex. 3,4,...,7,8), just loop through the indexes you want to add up and keep track of a total.

Comment: the op said 4 to 9. I assume the op meant from 4 to 9?

Comment: @KickButtowski This shows the principle involved. I think this is enough for OP to work it out for themselves, which generally facilitates better learning that being handed the code.

Comment: giving the code to the op who does not have any idea what is going on will not help . **we are not here to compete to  get more points.** we are here to help other to understand their issues better.

Comment: The best I can do now is remove that final chunk and give a better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Because your array is an String type it needs to be converted to int, After you do that you will have something like this example assuming that I'm making up those values , but it should still work for your code :). Don't forget to add the for loop at the end as I have it on my code so it can find the sum of your indexes. Hope it can help you!

```
    int sum = 0;
    int[] boat = new int[9];
    boat[0] = 2;
    boat[1] = 4;
    boat[2] = 6;
    boat[3] = 8;
    boat[4] = 10;
    boat[5] = 12;
    boat[6] = 14;
    boat[7] = 16;
    boat[8] = 18;


    for(int i = 3; i < boat.length ; i++){
        sum += boat[i];
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
```